# Android Studio - Target JRE version does not match project JDK version

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I recently migrated my project to Gradle 7.4.1, Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.2 and therefore also JDK 11 (from JDK 8), and everything is working fine except that when I run the unit tests in debug mode in Android Studio, it shows me this popup:

[image: Target JRE version (11.0.11) does not match project JDK version (version 1.8.0_242), will use sources from JDK: 11]

that says:

> Target JRE version (11.0.11) does not match project JDK version (version 1.8.0_242), will use sources from JDK: 11

To be clear, the popup is **not** shown in any other situation I tried so far, for example:

- building the app
- running the app in debug mode
- running the unit tests without the debug mode.

As you can see below, in Gradle settings I use JDK 11 (obviously; otherwise the project wouldn't work at all):

[image: Gradle settings in Android Studio show JDK 11]

I also used a "Choose Runtime" plugin to make sure the correct JDK is chosen:

[image: Choose runtime plugin shows JDK 11]

My environment variables are also correct:

```sh
❯ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/azabost/JetBrainsToolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-3/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home

❯ which java
/Users/azabost/JetBrainsToolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-3/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java

❯ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822, mixed mode)

❯ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-09 15:04:47 UTC
Revision:     36dc52588e09b4b72f2010bc07599e0ee0434e2e

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.11 (JetBrains s.r.o. 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.3 x86_64
```

I'm using Android Studio Bumblebee. Full version info:

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 17, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.3
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 16
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.marketplace (211.7628.36), com.jetbrains.ChooseRuntime (1.2), com.phrase.intellij (4.0.1), com.vladsch.idea.multimarkdown (3.0.202.112), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40)
```

I also reviewed some of the logs produced by Android Studio and they also seem correct:

```
2022-03-31 20:40:16,521 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2022-03-31 20:40:16,547 [     26]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env is skipped: IDE has been launched from a terminal (SHLVL=2) 
2022-03-31 20:40:16,574 [     53]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, 17 Feb 2022 08:12) 
2022-03-31 20:40:16,576 [     55]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (12.3, x86_64) 
2022-03-31 20:40:16,582 [     61]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 (JetBrains s.r.o.) 
2022-03-31 20:40:16,583 [     62]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2022-03-31 20:40:16,586 [     65]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Didea.vendor.name=Google -XX:ErrorFile=/Users/azabost/java_error_in_studio_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/azabost/java_error_in_studio.hprof -Xmx4096m -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Users/azabost/JetBrainsToolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-3/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions,/Users/azabost/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/studio.vmoptions -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2021.1 -Didea.executable=studio -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.vendor.name=Google -Didea.home.path=/Users/azabost/JetBrainsToolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-3/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents 
2022-03-31 20:40:16,586 [     65]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - library path: /Users/azabost/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:. 
2022-03-31 20:40:16,586 [     65]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - boot library path: /Users/azabost/JetBrainsToolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-3/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/lib 
2022-03-31 20:40:16,603 [     82]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - locale=en_GB JNU=UTF-8 file.encoding=UTF-8
  idea.config.path=/Users/azabost/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1
  idea.system.path=/Users/azabost/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1
  idea.plugins.path=/Users/azabost/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/plugins
  idea.log.path=/Users/azabost/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1

...

2022-03-31 21:32:13,214 [3116693]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Users/azabost/JetBrainsToolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-3/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home 
2022-03-31 21:32:13,590 [3117069]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build cancelled in 26 s 350 ms 
2022-03-31 21:32:17,748 [3121227]   WARN - idea.lint.common.LintIdeClient - com.toastfix.toasthandler_lint.registry.ToastHandlerIssueRegistry in /Users/azabost/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5cacc53feafc83908b80485cdde0ce02/transformed/jetified-ToastHandler-1.2.1/jars/lint.jar does not specify a vendor; see IssueRegistry#vendor 
2022-03-31 21:32:17,770 [3121249]   WARN - idea.lint.common.LintIdeClient - dagger.lint.DaggerIssueRegistry in /Users/azabost/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1d8efdd70f0fe0cb2ac32270bc2ae5c2/transformed/jetified-dagger-lint-aar-2.37/jars/lint.jar does not specify a vendor; see IssueRegistry#vendor 
2022-03-31 21:32:39,862 [3143341]   INFO - t.javadoc.JavaDocInfoGenerator - Wrong navElement: FUN; original = KtUltraLightMethodForSourceDeclaration:fetchAndCacheProductsWithSearchData of class class org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.classes.KtUltraLightMethodForSourceDeclaration 
2022-03-31 21:32:39,863 [3143342]   INFO - t.javadoc.JavaDocInfoGenerator - Wrong navElement: FUN; original = KtUltraLightMethodForSourceDeclaration:fetchAndCacheProductsWithSearchData of class class org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.classes.KtUltraLightMethodForSourceDeclaration 
2022-03-31 21:32:39,863 [3143342]   INFO - t.javadoc.JavaDocInfoGenerator - Wrong navElement: FUN; original = KtUltraLightMethodForSourceDeclaration:fetchAndCacheProductsWithSearchData of class class org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.classes.KtUltraLightMethodForSourceDeclaration 
2022-03-31 21:32:39,863 [3143342]   INFO - t.javadoc.JavaDocInfoGenerator - Wrong navElement: FUN; original = KtUltraLightMethodForSourceDeclaration:fetchAndCacheProductsWithSearchData of class class org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.classes.KtUltraLightMethodForSourceDeclaration 
2022-03-31 21:33:15,802 [3179281]   INFO -                         STDERR - invalid Unicode Property \p: /(?<=^[\s\d\p])\bV\b/ 
2022-03-31 21:33:56,220 [3219699]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Users/azabost/JetBrainsToolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-3/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home 
2022-03-31 21:33:56,220 [3219699]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Users/azabost/JetBrainsToolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-3/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home 
2022-03-31 21:33:56,228 [3219707]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:exampleModule:testDebugUnitTest] 
2022-03-31 21:33:56,231 [3219710]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Users/azabost/JetBrainsToolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-3/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home 
2022-03-31 21:33:56,232 [3219711]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--continue, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=2021.1.1 Patch 2, -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=/Users/azabost/projects/app-android/.gradle, --init-script, /private/var/folders/87/kglctjzn0znd_3kx9m038jf80000gn/T/ijmapper.gradle, --tests, net.example.app.ExampleTest.Example test, --init-script, /private/var/folders/87/kglctjzn0znd_3kx9m038jf80000gn/T/ijresolvers1.gradle] 
2022-03-31 21:33:56,233 [3219712]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --continue -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=2021.1.1 Patch 2 -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=/Users/azabost/projects/app-android/.gradle --init-script /private/var/folders/87/kglctjzn0znd_3kx9m038jf80000gn/T/ijmapper.gradle --tests net.example.app.ExampleTest.Example test --init-script /private/var/folders/87/kglctjzn0znd_3kx9m038jf80000gn/T/ijresolvers1.gradle
```

Perhaps it's worth mentioning that since the project is quite big (over 200 Gradle modules) and it consists of both Android library projects (i.e. plugin `com.android.library`) and pure Kotlin modules (i.e. no Android plugin, just the `kotlin` plugin), I try to keep the Gradle configurations in a single place and I try to configure all the modules in the same way using my own utility functions or Gradle built-in functions such as `allprojects`.

For example, to make sure all the modules have Kotlin's `jvmTarget` set to the same version, I use:

```kotlin
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(type = org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile::class) {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

and in each Android module I additionally do this:

```kotlin
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, most of the answers to similar problems I found on the internet usually mention setting the correct JDK path in IDE's Gradle settings and sometimes the configuration such as `jvmTarget` etc., and none of these tips worked for me so far (unless I did something wrong).

Do you know what causes that problem and how I could fix that?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm having a similar issue.  In my case the target JRE version is 8 and the JDK version is 11.0.13

Comment: @btschumy sorry, can't remember now since it was quite some time ago. If I have some time to spare, I will check that project again and let you know but I'm pretty sure I haven't done anything else to fix it so if the problem disappeared, it would be thanks to the Android Studio update or something.